# e.target not working in opera, chrome

Tags: jquery, html

I made a nav bar with jQuery, which is supposed to toggle the dropdowns on click. Most of the functionality works as it should.

```js
$(function()
{
    var tab = $(".dr-head");
    var childList = $(".child-list");
    tab.click(function(e)
    {
        e.stopPropagation();
        if ($(this).children("ul").css('opacity') == '0')
        {
            $("ul ul").css(
            {
                'opacity': '0'
            })
            $(this).children('ul').css(
            {
                'opacity': '1',
                'margin-top': '-15px'
            }).children('li').css(
            {
                'display': 'list-item',
                'position': 'relative',
                'left': '-75px',
                'padding-top': '12px'
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).children('ul').css(
            {
                'opacity': '0',
                'margin-top': '0'
            }).children('li').css(
            {
                'left': '-75px',
                'padding-top': '0px'
            });
        }
    });
    $("body").click(function(e)
    {
        var targ = $(".nav");
        if (e.target !== targ)
        {
            $(".dr-head").children("ul").css(
            {
                'opacity': '0'
            });
        }
    })
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="nav.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="nav.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://sarkelliancreed.comule.com">SarkellianCreed.com</a></li>
                <li class="dr-head"><a href="#">Learn</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://sarkelliancreed.comule.com/learn/web-design">Web Design</a></li>
                        <!-- <li></li> -->
                    </ul>  
                </li>
                <li class="dr-head"><a href="#">Tutorials and Snippets</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://sarkelliancreed.comule.com/c/snippets/">Password Generator</a></li>
                    </ul>    
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </body>
```

Everything works right, but when I click outside of the nav bar, the dropdowns do not go away. How can I make these work? http://sarkelliancreed.comule.com/c/new/nav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working fine.
Currently, your <body> element is only occupying height and width of navigation bar.

Once you add more content to your page, it will increase height of <body> element.

For example, here is one example where I set CSS:

```
height:500px
background-color:orange
```

for <body> and it will work when you click anywhere inside <body> element.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j66wjtmy/

Comment: So you're saying that whatever I click on is the nav bar, and therefore will not hide the dropdowns?

Comment: @yak613, I edited the post to explain how the height of body is playing the role.